Do there exist exotic derivations over beyond the commutator of 2 derivations?
Setup:
Consider a non commutative ring $R$ with two derivations defined on it $D_1, D_2$. That is they obey the Leibniz rule:
$$D_1(ab) = D_1(a)b + aD_1(b) \\ D_2(ab) = D_2(a)b + aD_2(b) $$
It follows immediately that the commutator $$ [D_1, D_2] = D_1 D_2 - D_2 D_1$$  Is also a derivation (which can be verified by algebra).
Now given a collection of derivations $d_1, d_2, d_3 ... d_k$  any linear combination $a_1 d_1 + a_2 d_2 + ... a_k d_k$ is also a derivation.
Question:
So it's natural to ask: are all finite-formula derivations on $R$ of the form $a D_1 + b D_2 + c [D_1 , D_2] $ ?
To me this would seem unlikely. The space of finite formulas is very large and it would seems entirely plausible that there could exist some crazy thing with wild coefficients and indices such as $1923338D^{11}_1 D^5_2 D^3_1 - 343433D^{17}_2D_1 ... $ that also obeys the Leibniz rule.
What would be a good way to find such an expression or prove they don't exist? This seems to be a bit of a tricky problem to model for computerized search as the space of formula to check grows very large very quickly.
Context:
This problem came to me from attempt to generalize some homework I had received in a a Diff Geo class (namely proving that $D_1 D_2 - D_2 D_1$ is a derivation).

What about iterated commutators such as $[D_1,[D_1,D_2]]$?

I don't see anything wrong with the commutator now. My professor had cited those would be 0 because the jacobi identity but this derivation suggests otherwise: $[D_1, [D_1, D_2]] + [D_1, [D_2, D_1]] + [D_2, [D_1, D_1]] = 0$ the third term contains $[D_1, D_1]$ so it must be 0. So this reduces to $[D_1, [D_1, D_2]] + [D_1, [D_2, D_1]]$. Note that $[D_1, D_2] = -[D_2, D_1]$ so this is just $0=0$. Without giving any constraint on the commutator.

I'll accept your result as an answer :) . I have modification of my question I can ask later but this is still useful to discuss with them first!

Iterated commutators such as $[D_1,[D_1,D_2]]$ may be nonzero in general. The Jacobi Identity does not kill these. In fact you will get potentially nonzero brackets of arbitrary degree, but they may happen to vanish due the nature of your ring or particular derivations.
